# jQuery Prepend Security

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, xss, csrf

Here is a rookie question, if I have a textarea that doesn't submit anywhere...

```
 <form onsubmit="return false;">
      <textarea name="new_title_text" id="new_title_text"></textarea>
 </form>
```

and I use jQuery to prepend the value of the textarea to a div...

```
var textValue = $('#new_title_text').val()
$('#myDiv').prepend('<div>' + textValue + '</div>');
```

Are there any security vulnerabilities with this? Can someone somehow inject JavaScript and preform XSS, CSRF or any other type of attack? I understand that once I submit the value to my server then it needs to be checked, but is there anything that can happen before submission?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4):

Basically you can't trust any validation done client side as people can (pretty easily) bypass JavaScript validation.

Do your proper validation and sanitation on your server and leave the client side validation simply for the user experience and to not "bother" your server with clearly invalid data - such as empty fields where a value is required.

---

Unless you are letting your users submit some PHP code or JavaSctipt code to be executed elsewhere on your site you should be safe.   Always remember **NOT** to trust any data coming in from users.  Treat all incoming data as a potential threat and sanitize anything you deal with if you plan to use it later.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone somehow inject JavaScript and preform XSS, CSRF or any other type of attack

Yes. You are injecting text into an HTML string without HTML-escaping, so any metacharacters in that string (`<` or `&`) will fail and may be vulnerable to injection attacks (eg `<script>...`).

The question is who is that someone? From your current code it doesn't appear possible for an external party to pre-fill the textarea, so it would have to be the user attacking themselves (not really a vulnerability).

So you either need to HTML-escape the string going into HTML, or, better, use DOM-style access methods like `.text()` and `.attr()` to set text content and attributes without using crude string markup generation. Or the creation shorthand:

```
$('#myDiv').prepend(
    $('<div>', {text: $('#new_title_text').val()})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that yes, it's unsafe to use prepend with untrusted data. However the exploitability does depend on the scenario. If an attacker can craft a url that causes that script to run with an untrusted value, you definitely have an XSS problem. If however a user can only trigger this himself by entering unsafe data and clicking the button, it's more safe, but not quite. This is often called self-xss and is sometimes exploited together with clickjacking etc.

For more info on unsafe jquery functions see: http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=127